# Print Writer write() and println()

Tags: java, networking, printwriter

I am currently learning Java Network programming. In one of my Programs I just have an EchoServer which sends the message of the client. But I recognized in the client that the `Printwriter.write()` method just sends when I close the writer while the `.println()` method works fine. I also tried it with and without auto-flush.

Works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Simple Echo Client");

    try{
        System.out.println("Waiting for Connection ...");
        InetAddress localAdress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

        try(Socket clientSocket = new Socket(localAdress,6000);
                PrintWriter out =new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),true);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()))){

            System.out.println("Connected to Server");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            while(true){
                System.out.print("Enter text: ");
                String inputLine = scanner.nextLine();
                if("quit".equals(inputLine)){
                    break;
                }
                out.println(inputLine);
                String response = br.readLine();
                System.out.println("Server response" + response);
            }
        }

    }catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Doesn't work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Simple Echo Client");

    try{
        System.out.println("Waiting for Connection ...");
        InetAddress localAdress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

        try(Socket clientSocket = new Socket(localAdress,6000);
                PrintWriter out =new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),true);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()))){

            System.out.println("Connected to Server");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            while(true){
                System.out.print("Enter text: ");
                String inputLine = scanner.nextLine();
                if("quit".equals(inputLine)){
                    break;
                }
                out.write(inputLine);
                String response = br.readLine();
                System.out.println("Server response" + response);
            }
        }

    }catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Could somebody explain to me why this is the case?

Comment: On top of the submitted answer, you may be interested in use DataFetcher with your socket. DataFetcher is an async InputStream reader with call back (ie listener) functionality: https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/DataFetcher.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the Printwriter.write() method just sends when I close the writer while the .println() method works fine

There seems there may be two problems here, the first having to do with writing and the second with reading:

1. The code creates a `PrintWriter` with automatic line flushing. When you use `println`, the new line results in the writer flushing. When using `write` without a new line, the `PrintWriter` does not flush (you can call `out.flush` after `out.write` to force a flush of the `Writer`).
2. Presuming the receiving end is using `Scanner.readLine()`, it expects a new line or will wait until it receives one. `println` automatically appends the new line to the end of the String, with `write` you must explicitly send the new line `out.write(line + "\n");`

Comment: thank you for your quick answer. But I also tried it without auto-flush and flushing the `PrintWriter` automatically with the `.flush()` method. But it didn't work.

Comment: Thank you with the  `out.write(line + "\n");` it works fine.

So just to repeat the `out.write()` expects a `+"\n"` so that I can flush it or I simply close the `PrintWriter`, which of course isn't a good way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I've absolutely seen this before. If you are using a PrintWriter or another Writer that has autoflush, you do not need to call flush(). But otherwise, to get the message to send, you've got to call flush() to get the content in the Writer / OutputStream to send.